# Rails: Migration and database differences between development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I recently deployed a website to heroku and I am having problems with the database. I am using ruby on rails and when I first created my local databases I used SQLite. When deploying to heroku I had to change my databases to Postgres and in the process several migration files got removed and changed into a single migration. Now, when I run the postgres database on my localhost, I am still seeing all of the columns in my database, but when I visit the page on heroku one of the columns is missing.

I have checked both my local console and the heroku console and the databases are now different. The local console includes all of the columns in the database and the heroku console is missing one of the columns in the database, but is generating all of the other columns correctly. I have tried running a rake task on heroku and have pushed the most recent changes to heroku.

I tried to to add an additional migration to add the missing column to the database, but whenever I try to rake the migration it tells me that attribute already exists. Any help I can get is appreciated!

Comment: Use `rake db:schema:load` to set up your db on heroku, it uses the `schema.rb` file to set everything up correctly.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: Thank you @Iceman! That worked perfectly!

Comment: @user7077886 Great, I made an answer to wrap things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to set up your database on heroku is with

```
rake db:schema:load
```

From the [guides on migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you)

> Migrations, mighty as they may be, are not the authoritative source
>   for your database schema. That role falls to either db/schema.rb or an
>   SQL file which Active Record generates by examining the database. They
>   are not designed to be edited, they just represent the current state
>   of the database.
>
> There is no need (and it is error prone) to deploy a new instance of
>   an app by replaying the entire migration history. It is much simpler
>   and faster to just load into the database a description of the current
>   schema.